# how to export filtered content of the trace window to text file in canoe

Tags: vector, canoe

I need to export the filtered content of a trace windows in CANoe.

For example I filter the channel and some specific frame id - and I want to filter and export also the data history of the log file.

right click-> export exports the entire log file.

right click-> export selection exports only a subset of the log.

How can I export only the filtered contend of a BLF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, any other method is welcomed.

On the connection between the ReplayBlock and the Network, right click and insert an output filter. In the filter is possible to select the frames that shall be passed or blocked.

In the trace window only the frames that are not blocked are shown and those can be exported directly.